# returning a copy of an object which is same as the original

Tags: java

```
package Test;
public class Test {
    class Book implements Cloneable {
        int bookID = 0;
        public void setID(int i) {
            this.bookID = i;
        }
    }
    class bookFactory {
        Book b;
        bookFactory() {
            b = new Book();
            b.setID(20);
        }
        public Book GetBooks() {
            return b;
            //now i want to
            //return a copy of b but it should be in the original state
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using b.clone but there is no clone function in b object.
  I can simply create a new object but I want to return the Book object 
  from the existing object but with original properties.

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this...

Comment: Override `clone()` in  `Book`with the specifications you want to have.

Comment: is there any method that i can use like b.clone();

Comment: Create a `Book(Book b)` constructor that copies the properties from the given book `b` into `this` book.

Comment: i was trying to use {b.clone()} without overriding now it works fine bt i would like to know some other ways of doing this tnx @yassin

Comment: @NullPointer Ok Sorry I did not understood it that way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12) approach.

```
class Book { 

    int id;

    //your normal constructor
    public Book(int id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    //your copy constructor
    public Book(Book book) {
        this.id = book.getId();
    }

    int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    //Also, you will want to override hashCode & equals 
    //if you plan on testing for equality and using containers.

}
```

Comment: What do you mean the prototype object ?  I think you're confused a bit here.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using b.clone but there is no clone function in b object

Implement the `clone` method as specified in [`Clonable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and you can invoke it.

```
class Book implements Cloneable {
    int bookID = 0;

    public void setID(int i) {
        this.bookID = i;
    }

    public Book clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Book) super.clone();
    }
}
```

But I would also prefer a **copy constructor** as [Amir Afghani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33900063/974186) said.